# How do I paste my email campaign?

Tags: css, html-email

I made a simple email campaign. I tried testing it by sending it to myself. However when I open it in my email it displays as raw html code. How do I email it to myself so that It displays as a campaign and not HTML raw code? I use gmail to send and open it.

Find below my the html code to my email campaign:

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=420, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
<style type="text/css">
/* Mobile-specific Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) { 
table[class=w0], td[class=w0] { width: 0 !important; }
table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[class=w10] { width:15px !important; }
table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class=w15] { width:15px !important; }
table[class=w30], td[class=w30], img[class=w30] { width:10px !important; }
table[class=w60], td[class=w60], img[class=w60] { width:10px !important; }
table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w125] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w130], td[class=w130], img[class=w130] { width:55px !important; }
table[class=w140], td[class=w140], img[class=w140] { width:90px !important; }
table[class=w160], td[class=w160], img[class=w160] { width:170px !important; }
table[class=w170], td[class=w170], img[class=w170] { width:100px !important; }
table[class=w180], td[class=w180], img[class=w180] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w195], td[class=w195], img[class=w195] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w220], td[class=w220], img[class=w220] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w240], td[class=w240], img[class=w240] { width:180px !important; }
table[class=w255], td[class=w255], img[class=w255] { width:185px !important; }
table[class=w275], td[class=w275], img[class=w275] { width:135px !important; }
table[class=w280], td[class=w280], img[class=w280] { width:135px !important; }
table[class=w300], td[class=w300], img[class=w300] { width:198px !important; }
table[class=w325], td[class=w325], img[class=w325] { width:95px !important; }
table[class=w360], td[class=w360], img[class=w360] { width:140px !important; }
table[class=w410], td[class=w410], img[class=w410] { width:180px !important; }
table[class=w470], td[class=w470], img[class=w470] { width:200px !important; }
table[class=w580], td[class=w580], img[class=w580] { width:280px !important; }
table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] { width:400px !important; }
table[class*=hide], td[class*=hide], img[class*=hide], p[class*=hide], span[class*=hide] { display:none !important; }
table[class=h0], td[class=h0] { height: 0 !important; }
p[class=footer-content-left] { text-align: center !important; }
#headline p { font-size: 30px !important; }
.article-content, #left-sidebar{ -webkit-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; }
.header-content, .footer-content-left {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 80% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 80% !important;}
img { height: auto; line-height: 100%;}
 } 
/* Client-specific Styles */
#outlook a { padding: 0; }  /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
body { width: 100% !important; }
.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
.ExternalClass { width: 100%; display:block !important; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
/* Reset Styles */
/* Add 100px so mobile switch bar doesn't cover street address. */
body { background-color: #ececec; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
img { outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
br, strong br, b br, em br, i br { line-height:100%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { line-height: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: blue !important; }
h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active { color: red !important; }
/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color.  There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */
h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */  
table td, table tr { border-collapse: collapse; }
.yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span {
color: black; text-decoration: none !important; border-bottom: none !important; background: none !important;
}   /* Body text color for the New Yahoo.  This example sets the font of Yahoo's Shortcuts to black. */
/* This most probably won't work in all email clients. Don't include code blocks in email. */
code {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
#background-table { background-color: #ececec; }
/* Webkit Elements */
#top-bar { border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; background-color: #043948; color: #e7cba3; }
#top-bar a { font-weight: bold; color: #e7cba3; text-decoration: none;}
#footer { border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
/* Fonts and Content */
body, td { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; }
.header-content, .footer-content-left, .footer-content-right { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes on header and footer. */
.header-content { font-size: 12px; color: #e7cba3; }
.header-content a { font-weight: bold; color: #e7cba3; text-decoration: none; }
#headline p { color: #e7cba3; font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; text-align: center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; }
#headline p a { color: #e7cba3; text-decoration: none; }
#left-sidebar .toc-item { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #00707b; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 6px; }
#left-sidebar .toc-item a { color: #00707b; text-decoration: none; }
#left-sidebar .toc-heading { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 15px; color:#9a9661; font-weight:bold; }
#left-sidebar .toc-heading a { color: #9a9661; text-decoration: none; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-heading { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height:15px; color: #9a9661; font-weight:bold; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-heading a { color: #9a9661; text-decoration:none; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-subhead { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #999999; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 16px; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-subhead a { color: #999999; text-decoration:none; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-content { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #9a9661; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 16px; }
#left-sidebar .left-column-content a { color: #00707b; text-decoration: none; }
#right-sidebar .toc-item { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #00707b; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 6px; }
#right-sidebar .toc-item a { color: #00707b; text-decoration: none; }
#right-sidebar .toc-heading { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 15px; color:#9a9661; font-weight:bold; }
#right-sidebar .toc-heading a { color: #9a9661; text-decoration: none; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-heading { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height:15px; color: #9a9661; font-weight:bold; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-heading a { color: #9a9661; text-decoration:none; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-subhead { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #999999; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 16px; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-subhead a { color: #999999; text-decoration:none; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-content { font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #9a9661; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 16px; }
#right-sidebar .left-column-content a { color: #00707b; text-decoration: none; }
.article-title { font-size: 18px; line-height:24px; color: #9a9661; font-weight:bold; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; }
.article-title a { color: #9a9661; text-decoration: none; }
.article-title.with-meta {margin-bottom: 0;}
.article-meta { font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; color: #ccc; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0;}
.article-content { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #444444; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 18px; font-family: HelveticaNeue, sans-serif; }
.article-content a { color: #00707b; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }
.article-content img { max-width: 100% }
.article-content ol, .article-content ul { margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; margin-left:19px; padding:0; }
.article-content li { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #444444; }
.article-content li a { color: #00707b; text-decoration:underline; }
.article-content p {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.footer-content-left { font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #e2e2e2; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.footer-content-left a { color: #e7cba3; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.footer-content-right { font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; color: #e2e2e2; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.footer-content-right a { color: #e7cba3; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
#footer { background-color: #043948; color: #e2e2e2; }
#footer a { color: #e7cba3; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }
#permission-reminder { white-space: normal; }
#street-address { color: #e7cba3; white-space: normal; }
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style _tmplitem="50" >
.article-content ol, .article-content ul {
   margin: 0 0 0 24px;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>
<![endif]--></head><body><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background-table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ececec">
            <table class="w640" style="margin:0 10px;" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w640" width="640" height="20"></td></tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="w640" width="640">
                        <table id="top-bar" class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#00707b">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="w15" width="15"></td>
        <td class="w325" width="350" valign="middle" align="left">
            <table class="w325" width="350" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w325" width="350" height="8"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <div class="header-content"><webversion>Web Version</webversion><span class="hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <preferences lang="en">Update preferences</preferences>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe></span></div>
            <table class="w325" width="350" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w325" width="350" height="8"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
        <td class="w255" width="255" valign="middle" align="right">
            <table class="w255" width="255" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w255" width="255" height="8"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>

        <td valign="middle"><fblike><img src="https://img.createsend1.com/img/templatebuilder/like-glyph.png" border="0" width="8" height="14" alt="Facebook icon"=""></fblike></td>
        <td width="3"></td>
        <td valign="middle"><div class="header-content"><fblike>Like</fblike></div></td>


        <td class="w10" width="10"></td>
        <td valign="middle"><tweet><img src="https://img.createsend1.com/img/templatebuilder/tweet-glyph.png" border="0" width="17" height="13" alt="Twitter icon"=""></tweet></td>
        <td width="3"></td>
        <td valign="middle"><div class="header-content"><tweet>Tweet</tweet></div></td>


        <td class="w10" width="10"></td>
        <td valign="middle"><forwardtoafriend lang="en"><img src="https://img.createsend1.com/img/templatebuilder/forward-glyph.png" border="0" width="19" height="14" alt="Forward icon"=""></forwardtoafriend></td>
        <td width="3"></td>
        <td valign="middle"><div class="header-content"><forwardtoafriend lang="en">Forward</forwardtoafriend></div></td>

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
            <table class="w255" width="255" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w255" width="255" height="8"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="w15" width="15"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="header" class="w640" width="640" align="center" bgcolor="#00707b">

    <table class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr><td class="w30" width="30"></td><td class="w580" width="580" height="30"></td><td class="w30" width="30"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
            <td class="w580" width="580">
                <div align="center" id="headline">
                    <p>
                        <strong><singleline label="Title">ABC Widgets</singleline></strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>


</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="complex-content-row"><td class="w640" width="640"><table class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="w15" width="15" bgcolor="#e2e2e2"></td>
        <td id="left-sidebar" class="w140" width="140" bgcolor="#e2e2e2" valign="top" align="left">

            <table class="w140" width="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="w140" width="140">
                        <p align="left" class="left-column-heading"><singleline>TABLE OF CONTENTS</singleline></p>
                        <tableofcontents>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td width="3"></td>
                                    <td valign="top"><p align="left" class="toc-item">•</p></td>
                                    <td width="6"></td>
                                    <td valign="top"><p align="left" class="toc-item"><strong><repeatertitle></strong></p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </tableofcontents>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>


            <table class="w140" width="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="w140" width="140">
                        <div align="left" class="left-column-heading"><singleline label="Title">IN OTHER NEWS</singleline></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <repeater>

            </repeater>

        </td>
        <td class="w15" width="15" bgcolor="#e2e2e2"></td>
        <td class="w300" width="300" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top">
            <table class="w300" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr><td class="w300" width="300" height="30"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <table class="w300" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
                    <td class="w240" width="240">
                        <repeater>


                            </repeater>
                    </td>
                    <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            </td>
            <td class="w15" width="15" bgcolor="#e2e2e2"></td>
            <td id="right-sidebar" class="w140" width="140" bgcolor="#e2e2e2" valign="top" align="left">


                <table class="w140" width="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody><tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="25"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w140" width="140">
                            <div align="left" class="left-column-heading"><singleline label="Title">ALSO OF INTEREST</singleline></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <repeater>
                    <layout label="Text only">
                        <table class="w140" width="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="w140" width="140">
                                    <p align="left" class="left-column-subhead"><singleline label="Title">Add a title</singleline></p>
                                    <div align="left" class="left-column-content"><multiline label="Description">Enter your description</multiline></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </layout>
                    <layout label="Text with image">
                        <table class="w140" width="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="w140" width="140"><p align="left" class="left-column-subhead"><singleline label="Title">Add a title</singleline></p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="w140" width="140"><img editable="true" label="Image" width="140" class="w140" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td class="w140" width="140" height="15"></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="w140" width="140"><div align="left" class="left-column-content"><multiline label="Description">Enter your description</multiline></div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </layout>
                </repeater>

            </td>
            <td class="w15" width="15" bgcolor="#e2e2e2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="w640" width="640"><table class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="w170" width="170" bgcolor="#e2e2e2" height="15"></td>
                            <td class="w300" width="300" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="15"></td>
                            <td class="w170" width="170" bgcolor="#e2e2e2" height="15"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td class="w640" width="640">
    <table id="footer" class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#043948">
        <tbody><tr><td class="w30" width="30"></td><td class="w580 h0" width="360" height="30"></td><td class="w0" width="60"></td><td class="w0" width="160"></td><td class="w30" width="30"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
            <td class="w580" width="360" valign="top">
            <span class="hide"><p id="permission-reminder" align="left" class="footer-content-left"></p></span>
            <p align="left" class="footer-content-left"><preferences lang="en">Edit your subscription</preferences> | <unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe></p>
            </td>
            <td class="hide w0" width="60"></td>
            <td class="hide w0" width="160" valign="top">
            <p id="street-address" align="right" class="footer-content-right"></p>
            </td>
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="w30" width="30"></td><td class="w580 h0" width="360" height="15"></td><td class="w0" width="60"></td><td class="w0" width="160"></td><td class="w30" width="30"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="w640" width="640" height="60"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table></body></html>
```

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: "How do I email it to myself so that It displays as a campaign and not HTML raw code? I use gmail to send and open it." Not by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hacky way to do it is to create your email html and view it in a browser as a web page. Now `ctrl+a` select all the rendered html from the page, and paste it into the email you are composing.

This is definitely not the way to go about sending email campaigns, but it *will* send it as rendered html.

Just note, that your images need to be hosted online, otherwise they will not show up.

Answer (score 2):

Add `MIME-Version: 1.0` and `Content-type: text/html` to your mail headers.

Comment: Where do I find the mail headers in gmail?

Comment: It has nothing to do with gmail. Headers are part of what your mail creating software send to the mail server.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean I should add it to my code then?  Kindly demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. Email clients will escape your html characters, hence you seeing raw html in your inbox, unless you send with the proper MIME headers from a program or Email Service Provider.

For testing webmail clients, I use [this google docs spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmxApiq9b5Q9dGpyNy1jMjhrUk0tUkVFcmpJYlF2d2c&newcopy=true) which contains a script that uses your gmail account to send html email. I wouldn't use it for mass mailings however because google will probably block your account, but I use it to test send frequently to a few accounts without issue.